# Emulate Fn keys when notebook is docked and lid closed

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, docking-station

The title pretty much says it. Is it possible to emulate Fn keys (XP SP3) on an external keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the BIOS.  Some BIOSes offer Fn emulation for external keyboards.  My old Dell laptop used ScrollLock as Fn.